# SQL oracle add check constraint to an existing table

Tags: sql, oracle

Im using SQL/PL developer and I have a table named Appeal, that has 2 attributs OpenDate and CloseDate. And I want to add a constraint to ensure that open date will be smaller than close date. I have a lot of records in this table.

this is my code:

```
alter table appeal
add constraint Check_Dates
check (OpenDate < CloseDate)
```

and I get en error saying:
    ORA-02293: cannot validate (STSTEM.CHECK_DATES) - check constraint violated

any ieads?
Thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constraint looks right, I have tested it:

```
create table appeal ( OpenDate date,  CloseDate date);

alter table appeal
add constraint Check_Dates
check (OpenDate < CloseDate);

insert into appeal values ( sysdate, sysdate - 1 );
```

And here the result:

> Schema Creation Failed: ORA-02290: check constraint
>   (USER_4_44096.CHECK_DATES) violated

**Problem is than you have already rows with OpenDate < CloseDate values in your database. Fix it before create constraint.** Look behavior changing sentences order:

```
create table appeal ( OpenDate date,  CloseDate date);

insert into appeal values ( sysdate, sysdate - 1 );

alter table appeal
add constraint Check_Dates
check (OpenDate < CloseDate);
```

And here your issue:

> Schema Creation Failed: ORA-02293: cannot validate
>   (USER_4_E4450.CHECK_DATES) - check constraint violated

Comment: I see... But I already have data in the table that I inserted before that constrain was added, so could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Explained now on answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
alter table appeal
add constraint Check_Dates
check (OpenDate < CloseDate) ENABLE NOVALIDATE;

You will have check the previous data for errors but any new Data will fall under the CHECK